# PHP Checkbox Validation Using Variable

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to apply some validation to my code to produce an error if no item has been selected from the list of items dsiplayed (comes from txt file) I've set validation up if the visitor name is not entered however the name given for the checkbox is a variable `<input type='checkbox' name='$partno'>` so it's making it very difficult to set some validation up, any ideas how to implement this would be appreciated.

```
 <script>
        function validateName()
        {
            var x=document.forms["purchase"]["visitor"].value;
            if (x==null || x=="")
            {
                alert("Visitor name must be entered");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Items Available</h1>

    <form name="purchase" action="confirm.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateName()">
        <table>

            <h3>Visitor Name: <input type='text' name='visitor'></h3>
            <tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>Price</th><th>&#10004;</th><th>QTY</th></tr>

            <?php
            if (!($data = file('items.txt'))) {
                echo 'ERROR: Failed to open file! </body></html>';
                exit;
            }
            foreach ($data as $thedata) {
                list($partno, $name, $description, $price, $image) = explode('|', $thedata);
                echo "<tr><td><img src='$image' width='60' height='60' alt='image'></td><td><h3>$name</h3></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$description</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>&pound;$price</b></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='$partno'></td><td><input type='text' size='1' name='qty' value='1'</td></tr>";
            }
            ?> 

        </table>
```

So far I've tried...

```
function validateName()
    {
        var x=document.forms["purchase"]["$partno"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
            alert("Select atleast one item");
            return false;
```

which has failed miserably.

New Code

```
<script>
        function validateName()
        {
            var x=document.getElementById("purchase").value
            if (x==null || x=="")
            {
                alert("Visitor name must be entered");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Items Available</h1>

    <form id="purchase" name="purchase" action="confirm.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateName()">
        <table>

            <h3>Visitor Name: <input type='text' name='visitor'></h3>
            <tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>Price</th><th>&#10004;</th><th>QTY</th></tr>

            <?php
            if (!($data = file('items.txt'))) {
                echo 'ERROR: Failed to open file! </body></html>';
                exit;
            }
            foreach ($data as $thedata) {
                list($partno, $name, $description, $price, $image) = explode('|', $thedata);
                echo "<tr><td><img src='$image' width='60' height='60' alt='image'></td><td><h3>$name</h3></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$description</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>&pound;$price</b></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='$partno'></td><td><input type='text' size='1' name='qty' value='1'</td></tr>";
            }
            ?> 

        </table>
```

Comment: function validateItem()
            {
                var x=document.getElementById("purchase").value
                if (x==null || x=="")
                {
                    alert("Select atleast one item");
                    return false;

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use the HTML attribute "id" in the form through which the JavaScript will access it.

```
<form id="purchase" name="purchase" action="confirm.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateName()">
```

and then use the following to access it :

```
document.getElementById("purchase").value
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with JavaScript could you expand on the "id" part of your answer.

Comment: use as <form id="purchase" name="purchase" and rest will be the same>

Comment: How is it then possible to validate that to ensure at least one or more boxes have been ticked? Apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: `function validateItem()
            {
                var x=document.getElementById("purchase").value;
                if (x==null || x=="")
                {
                    alert("Select atleast one item");
                    return false;` I tried this but no joy

Comment: then use-- x=document.getElementById("purchase").value  to compare your values use this x

Comment: I've tried this however, regardless of if the boxes next to each item have been ticked or not I always get the alert "Visitor name must be entered"

Comment: Perhaps the id part needs to be within `<input type='checkbox' name='$partno'>`

Comment: then use-- x=document.getElementById("purchase").value  to compare your values use this x  if you are using                           var x=document.forms["purchase"]["$partno"].value; then "$partno" will not work as it has not been defined in the form attibutes as "purchase".

Comment: `x=document.getElementById("purchase").value
                if (x==null || x=="")
                {
                    alert("Visitor name must be entered");
                    return false;` Removing the var makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the $partno variable then you should pass it as hidden

```
<input type="hidden" value=$partno">

function validateName()
   {
    var x=document.forms["purchase"]["$partno"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
     {
        alert("Select atleast one item");
        return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do fine for you --

```
<h3>Visitor Name: <input type='text' id="name" name='visitor'></h3>
```

and for script use

```
<script>
    function validateName()
    {
        var x = document.getElementById("name").value
        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
            alert("Visitor name must be entered");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's the tickbox I'm trying to validate, i.e. if no tick boxes are selected an error is displayed not the visitor name... thanks anyway.